# I want extract download and upload speed result from speedtest-csv cli

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I want to extract the speed test of upload and download only from bash.
I have 3000++ line on csv(tab) file and just want extract last row ~ 85.41 and 9.15 only.

```
2019-03-02 11:00:02     2019-03-02 11:00:30     ABC ISP  XX.XX.XX.XXX    TEST SERVER LONG NAME   302.20  88.641  85.41   9.15    http://www.speedtest.net/result/111111111.png
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as each line has the same number of fields, a trivial solution in `awk` is simply:

```
awk '{ print $14, $15 }'
```

For example, either `echo` your line and pipe it to the `awk` statement above or put it in a file and use that as the argument and you would have:

```
$ awk '{ print $14, $15 }' ~/tmpd/file
85.41 9.15
```

You can format the output any way you like. If `file` has 3000 lines, you will get the same field output for each of the 3000 lines.

If you only want the values from the **"last row"** (e.g. last line) in the file, then you can do:

```
$ awk '{ a=$14; b=$15 } END { print a, b }' ~/tmpd/file
```

or combine `tail` and `awk`, e.g.

```
$ tail -n1 ~/tmpd/file | awk '{ print $14, $15 }'
```